# Folder is not copying properly from laptop to hard drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

Hi I am using [WD elements 2 TB hard](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/wd-2tb-elements-usb-30/1457692?utm_source=earth_feed&utm_campaign=21_53&utm_medium=100761012) drive. I tried to copy folder (6gb movies) from my windows 7 laptop. It shows copy is completed but when I eject it and again connect it is showing empty folder.Also I checked the hard disk size and it shows that files are present on the hard disk but they are displaying.

But I just copied same movies files (.mkv and .mp4) files they are displaying and also I can run it.

I tried with other folders also and causing same problem.

Can any one suggest what happens to my hard disk and how can I resovle it.

Here is the detail information

```
Specifications
Interface - USB 3.0 and USB 2.0
Capacity  - 2 TB 

Compatibility
Operating System -  Windows/Mac 

File system - exFat
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a virus in your system which is hiding your folders.

the files are there in your Hard drive to see it unhide the files(from the file menu options).

Install a latest antivirus and scan your system.

Comment: I already tried it. Also there are some older folders and I can see its data.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would make sure there are no hidden files from Tools > Folder Options > View Tab. In addition, you can try with the attrib -h -r -s /s /d z:*.* command as written, where z is the letter of your external  drive.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx – more details about the Attrib command.

Hope this helps